# I have a connecting flight from Vienna to Delhi with layover at DMM for approximately 7 hours (Wizz Air and Indigo). Will i require transit visa?

Tags: transit-visas, saudi-arabia

The flight carrier from Vienna is Wizz air and connecting flight is of Indigo. No checked baggage.

Comment: Separate tickets?

Comment: Since both are LCC, this is extremely likely

Comment: Wizz Air only sells individual flights. You basically have two independent tickets, not "a connecting flight". One from Vienna to Dammam, and one from Dammam to Delhi.

Comment: What is your citizenship?

Comment: I am in a similar situation. Pegasus airline from Frankfurt to Dammam and then air India to Delhi. Pegasus won't help with visa issues. How can I manage?

Comment: You need to have all paperwork required to enter Dammam. What this is depends on your citizenship (and resident permits, etc)\

Answer (score 3):

These are two different tickets. You will need full documentation to legally enter Saudi Arabia. What that documentation is, depends on your citizenship(s).

While you may be able to make the transfer without having to enter Saudi Arabia, Whizz Air will not let you board without showing proper entry documentation.